# How do I enable iframes in code

Tags: iframe, targeting

I have the code for iframes but for some reason, it won't work. It will display either an error message or an empty blank, white box. I am not sure if I need to enable the code that the iframe is targeting or if there is something wrong with the "extension".

```
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" width="80%" height="380px" scrolling="yes">
```

Comment: what's the error message displaying?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you didn't close the iframe tag?
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

```
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" width="80%" height="380px" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```